# Can I process jaxb annotations at compile-time?

Tags: java, android, annotations, jaxb, jaxb2

I am experimenting to see if I can somehow make JAXB work on Android in a limited scenario. (using other libraries is not an option).

I have gotten pretty far but at the moment I am stuck getting the following stack trace probably because Dalvik does not allow it.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  643): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: getDeclaredAnnotations
E/AndroidRuntime(  643):    at java.lang.Package.getDeclaredAnnotations(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  643):    at java.lang.Package.getAnnotations(Package.java:97)
E/AndroidRuntime(  643):    at java.lang.Package.getAnnotation(Package.java:80)
E/AndroidRuntime(  643):    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.annotation.RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.getPackageAnnotation(RuntimeInlineAnnotationReader.java:129)
```

I took care to remove all package level annotations and to my JAXB context with the specific class that I have annotated for JAXB:

```
JAXBContext jaxb_context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Num.class);
```

**Can I make JAXB do all its discovery at compile-time, rather than at run-time?** (much like DataNucleus can process JPA annotations at compile-time)